# PHP Echo text Color

Tags: php, echo

How do I change the color of an echo message and center the message in the PHP I've written. The line I have is:

`echo 'Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply!';`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about writing out some HTML tags and some CSS if you're outputting this to the browser?

```
echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply!</span>';
```

Won't work from console though, only through browser.

Answer (score 134):

How about writing out some escape sequences?

```
echo "\033[01;31m Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply! \033[0m";
```

Won't work through browser though, only from console ;))

Comment: is there any documentation about this colors and options?

Comment: Here's the script that I use for this purpose, http://asheepapart.blogspot.com/2011/02/add-color-to-php-echo-in-cli.html

Comment: You also have to ensure that your terminal emulator is using a standard colour scheme, otherwise red may not display as red.

Comment: In case you're looking for a command line solution:
https://github.com/box/bart/blob/master/src/Bart/EscapeColors.php
Thanks to @Ben for the original link

Answer (score 3):

And if you are using Command line on Windows, download a program ANSICON that enables console to accept color codes. ANSICON is available at https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases

Answer (score 3):

this works for me every time try this.

`echo "<font color='blue'>".$myvariable."</font>";`

since font is not supported in html5 you can do this

```
echo "<p class="variablecolor">".$myvariable."</p>";
```

then in css do

```
.variablecolor{
color: blue;}
```

Comment: The <font> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: you can do this in html5 and css echo "<p class="variablecolor">".$myvariable."</p>";

.variablecolor{
 color: blue;
}

Comment: I wasn't actually sure if terminals used html/CSS standards but I thought it was worth commenting. I've reverted my down vote though as it was a bad assumption sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but no one responded to the question regarding centering text in a terminal.

```
/**
 * Centers a string of text in a terminal window
 *
 * @param string $text The text to center
 * @param string $pad_string If set, the string to pad with (eg. '=' for a nice header)
 *
 * @return string The padded result, ready to echo
 */
function center($text, $pad_string = ' ') {
    $window_size = (int) `tput cols`;
    return str_pad($text, $window_size, $pad_string, STR_PAD_BOTH)."\n";
}

echo center('foo');
echo center('bar baz', '=');
```

Comment: Yes, just change `STR_PAD_BOTH` to `STR_PAD_LEFT` (because you're applying the padding on the left side to push the message to the right). See the [doc on `str_pad`](https://secure.php.net/str_pad)

Answer (score 1):

If you want send ANSI color to console, get this tiny package,

http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Color

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php 
echo '<i style="color:blue;font-size:30px;font-family:calibri ;">
      hello php color </i> ';
//we cannot use double quote after echo , it must be single quote.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it echoing out to a browser, you should use CSS. This would require also having the comment wrapped in an HTML tag. Something like:

```
echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center">
      Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply!
      </p>';
```