# Changing the color of PHP text

Tags: php, html, css

I was wondering if you can change the colour of your print and echo text so that when it is displayed on your HTML page it's not simply in black? Cheers.

Comment: Yes. But you'll have to do it with HTML/CSS. Emit the information between a pair of tags that you apply some styling rules to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Echo text Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691646/php-echo-text-color)

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in html, always.

```
<?php echo "<span style='color:blue;'>blue text</span>"; ?>
```

If you're doing this in command line, it's a bit different. You'd need to create a library or find an existing one. Example: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-class-for-coloring-php-command-line-cli-scripts-output-php-output-colorizing-using-bash-shell-colors/

Comment: The question was tagged as html/css, although I agree it's not clear!

Answer (score 1):

Sure :

```
<?php

echo "<p style='color:blue'> Hello ! </p>";

?>
```