# How to color and center the 'ECHO' [PHP]

Tags: php, styles, echo

That's how my code looks like:

```
if (in_array($name, $blacklist)) {
    echo "Admins cannot be resolved. $name BLACKLISTED! ";
} else {
    $api1 = file_get_contents("http://www.abrasivecraft.com/api.php?cmd=10&username={$name}");
    echo "$name 's IP is: $api1";
}
```

where it says :" { echo "Admins cannot be resolved. $name BLACKLISTED! "; } "

I want this output to be centered, bold and colored in red, also I want it to appear below the box where I enter the username in the following screenshot,that's how it looks like when I enter this blacklisted name.

http://prntscr.com/4io7rc

**NOTE:** I've seen this [PHP Echo text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691646/php-echo-text-color) 
But didn't help me at all...

Comment: Use css / html for that.

Comment: Be more specific please, I don't understand what you mean, and how I will use HTML with php?

**#BEGINNER**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be.

```
if(in_array($name,$blacklist))
{
    echo "<div style='display: block; color:red;'>Admins cannot be resolved. " . $name . " BLACKLISTED!</div>";
}
```

### ( but you should look more into html & css )

Comment: after modifying it to look like that:

 `
if(in_array($name,$blacklist))
{
 echo "<div style="color:red;>Admins cannot be resolved. $name BLACKLISTED!</div>";
}
 `

that's what I got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' `

Comment: try again now. watch the single and double quotes